# How to execute JavaScript Function after Ajax Call in Rails?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am rendering a few elements with an Ajax call in rails, however another function of mine needs to reference those elements. The issue I am facing now is that the function can not grab these elements, unless the Ajax request has actually finished. Is there some way of running a javascript function in Rails after the ajax call?

For example:

**fetch_cards.js.erb**

```
var cards = $('.cards'); // only fetches previous cards, not the new ones

my_function( cards );
```

**cards_controller.rb**

```
def fetch_cards
    respond_to do |format|
        format.js
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean, but javascript offers you the ability to listen for an ajax call to be completed. Since you already use jQuery, you can do the following:

```
$.ajax('your/resources.json', 
    complete: function(jqXHR, status){
      // this will be executed once the server has completed your request
      my_function(cards);
    }
);
```

You probably want to extend this function with more specific callback functions (`success`, `error`), you can find more info on the [jQuery API docs](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Comment: Thanks for the help! That pretty much fixed it, just I removed the "url". Also a "}" is missing for "complete:". :)

Comment: Yep it is a bit of a sloppy example, I will update it for future reference!